# Original proof of the Invariance of Domain Theorem (in English)?

Tags: algebraic-topology, math-history

Does anyone know where I can find a translation of the original proof of the Invariance of Domain Theorem in English?  Wikipedia cites the original proof to be in:

*Beweis der Invarianz des n-dimensionalen Gebiets, Mathematische Annalen* 71 (1912), pages 305–315; see also 72 (1912), pages 55–56.

I was curious to finding an English translation to this if possible.  Or at least another proof that follows Brouwer's proof in English.

Comment: If it is really important for you, then you should ask a student at university, who studies German, for a translation. I think there are a few people who would do it for some money.

Comment: This is just one more instance of why Esperanto was created.